# How can I add a custom filter in products query filter input with custom code for the apply in magento 2

Tags: magento2, graphql, customfilter

Hello every one I develop a headless magento website and I want to ask if there is a way to add a custom filter method to add on the Product filter input in graphql. For example I want the filter to apply if a product's sku is on a custom db table. I already tried to add it via graphql di xml but i didn't work at all.

Comment: any luck on this?